# Generate a List on viewmodel

Tags: c#, linq, list, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i will like to generate list and bind into viewmodel but i was get error below, did i define wrong attribute?

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel]'.

Edit.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<table>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Answer)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

SURV_AnswerController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SurveyTool.Models;

namespace SurveyTool.Controllers
{
    public class SURV_AnswerController : Controller
    {
        private SurveyToolDB db = new SurveyToolDB();
        //
        // GET: /SURV_Answer/

        public ActionResult Edit(int Survey_ID)
        {
            AnswerQuestionViewModel viewmodel = new AnswerQuestionViewModel();

            var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                        join s in db.SURV_Question_Model
                        on r.Qext_Question_ID equals
                        s.Question_ID
                        where s.Question_Survey_ID == Survey_ID
                        orderby s.Question_Position ascending
                        select r;

            foreach(var item in query)
            {

                viewmodel.Question = item.Qext_Text;
            }

            return View(viewmodel);
        }

    }
}
```

AnswerQuestionViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace SurveyTool.Models
{
    public class AnswerQuestionViewModel
    {
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing only an object to view where view expects a collection.

Comment: Moreover, you overwrite the value in viewmodel.Questions during the loop . Something's wrong in code logic. Think again - what do you want to pass to a View. It looks like you want to pass an array. Then generate an array in an action but not a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returning only a single `AnswerQuestionViewModel` item, not a collection. In your `public ActionResult Edit(int Survey_ID)` method, change

```
AnswerQuestionViewModel viewmodel = new AnswerQuestionViewModel();
```

to

```
List<AnswerQuestionViewModel> viewmodel = new List<AnswerQuestionViewModel>();
```

and then in the `foreach` loop

```
foreach(var item in query)
{
    viewmodel.Add(new AnswerQuestionViewModel() { Question = item.Qext_Text });
}
return View(viewmodel);
```

**Edit**

Note there are also problems with your view. You use of a `foreach` loop generates duplicate `name` attributes so the collection will not be bound on post back. It also generates invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes. You need to use a `for` loop of a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof  `AnswerQuestionViewModel`. Using a `for` loop, it needs to be

```
@model List<SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Question)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Answer)
    }
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

However this will only post back the `Answer` property of your model. You do not have any property identifying the ID of the question so you probably need an additional property for the ID, and include a hidden input for it in the view

Comment: Does this need to be changed in view as well model IEnumerable<SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel> to model List<SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel> ?

Comment: Yes, but only because their are other problems with the view (it will not post back because of the duplicate `name` attributes and its also invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes. I will update my answer with extra info shortly

Comment: Thanks again Stephen, after working out some time, this is what i want actually. Really appreciate your prompt guidance :') Will keep learning on it!

Comment: See also update - you need to correct the view code or binding will fail when you post

Comment: Very useful and clear info! Working on it now! Thanks!